# jasny bootstrap off canvas - how to set autohide and not showing offcanvas initially

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I am using [Jasny Bootstrap Offcanvas](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas). I want to initially set `autohide` option to `false`, however when I do that, the corresponding offcanvas shows, which I want to avoid.

How can I set `autohide` to `false` and prevent offcanvas from being shown?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I want to set autohide to true. Setting `toggle: false` works for me:

```
$("nav").offcanvas({ autohide: true, toggle: false });
```